# How to boot from Windows 7 installation USB and install it after Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, hp

I have Ubuntu 13.04 installed on my HP Pavilion PC, and I am able to boot from Ubuntu live USB, but when I try to install Windows 7 from USB my computer boots to Ubuntu. My Windows installation USB works fine to install Windows in VirtualBox. I already have Windows 7 installed inside VirtualBox using my Windows installation USB. Any help and advice to solve the issue would be highly appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that if you are trying to get a dual boot system, you should install windows first, then Ubuntu.
This is because the Windows Bootloader tends to overwrite the entire hard-drive. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Install_Ubuntu_after_Windows